# Microsoft Graph API - OnlineMeeting - How to allow who joins the meeting get access to full chat history?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm creating OnlineMeetings with Microsoft Graph API and I can't find any option on [Microsoft Graph API documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/api-reference/beta/resources/onlinemeeting.md#properties) that would allow who joins the meeting access the full chat history.

Business case:

1. Create OnlineMeeting and make the join link available to some people.
2. Immediately, 3 persons join the call and share also some information/files through chat.
3. 30 minutes later, more team members join the call with the link provided on step 1 and they can't see the chat history.

**However, if you remove the participant from the meeting and then invite (Teams Application interface, not Graph API), there is a question to consent access to chat history/files.**

I need to know if this option that appears on the Teams App (UI) is available for GraphAPI, so everyone that joins this meeting will have access to full chat history, no matter at what time they joined the meeting.

```py
url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings"

payload = {
   'subject': 'Meeting Subject'
}

headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN'
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you share what you have done? your code?

Comment: You can list [chat messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) in call /chats/{threadId}/messages

Comment: @Trinetra-MSFT, I have updated the question with more info, I need to know if the option available through the Teams App (UI) is available for the OnlineMeetings endpoint, so we auto consent access to chat history to everyone that joins the meeting, something like the option autoAdmittedUsers or capabilities? Thanks!

Comment: User joined a meeting later can't see message history this is by design